# Wireless keyboard/mouse immune to USB3 radio frequency interference?

Tags: usb, wireless, keyboards, mice

I have always had really bad luck with wireless keyboards and mice on computers that have USB3 connectors.  When plugging the receiver mini-dongle into a USB3 port (or even near a USB3 port) both the keyboard and mouse suffer from lag and missed events.

I just gave up after a while, but when looking for something else I found this article: [USB 3.0* Radio Frequency Interference on 2.4 GHz Devices](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/io/universal-serial-bus/usb3-frequency-interference-paper.html) on Intel's website, which reads in part:

> ... the noise from USB 3.0 data spectrum can be high
>   (in the 2.4–2.5 GHz range). This noise can radiate from the USB 3.0 connector on a 
>   PC platform, the USB 3.0 connector on the peripheral device or the USB 3.0 cable. If 
>   the antenna of a wireless device operating in this band is placed close to any of the 
>   above USB 3.0 radiation channels, it can   pick up the broadband noise. The broadband 
>   noise emitted from a USB 3.0 device can affect the SNR and limit the sensitivity of any 
>   wireless receiver whose antenna is physically located close to the USB 3.0 device. This 
>   may result in a drop in throughput on the wireless link.

This describes the issues I've encountered perfectly.

**The question**: Does anybody make a wireless kb/mouse that is immune to USB3 RFI?  I have searched several times, and usually my Google-fu is quite good, but it fails me here.

Comment: Can someone with the necessary rep please create a `usb3` tag and add it to the post? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

There's a little trick you can use to get around this.  Get a USB extension cable.   Then plug the extension cable into a 2.x port (assuming your components are 2.x and don't lose performance on those ports) and plug the dongle into the other end.  This gives you the length to get the actual wireless receiver away from the interference from the USB3 ports.